# Find the type of a panel displayed in the UI

Tags: python, scripting, interface

Is there an easy way to find the type of an panel displayed in the UI?

*Right click* -> *Edit Source* does not work for panels in the tools/properties regions.
It is definately possible to access some of them.

[image: example panel]

I tried to create a [list](http://www.pasteall.org/49676) and retrieve some info from `bpy.types.*` but it is still difficult sometimes to find the correct panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If *Edit Source* fails, then it's created by a script on-the-fly (through PyConsole or Text Editor), or it's hardcoded in C - which is more likely the case. You won't find the panel subclasses in `bpy.types` in the latter case, they aren't exposed to python.

I usually try to find similar panels or even other types via Auto-complete in the PyConsole, to figure out the naming scheme. Take the Grease Pencil panel for instance:

There is no `bpy.types.GREASE*`, so no header, menu, panel or operator. A different name is used apparantly. We can also check for any type that contains "grease":

```
>>> [d for d in dir(bpy.types) if "grease" in d.lower()]
['BlendDataGreasePencils', 'CLIP_PT_tools_grease_pencil', 'GreasePencil', 'GreasePencilLayers']
```

Nothing useful in there, I would now try another part of the name or an abbreviation:

```
>>> [d for d in dir(bpy.types) if "pencil" in d.lower()]
['BlendDataGreasePencils', 'CLIP_PT_tools_grease_pencil', 'DOPESHEET_MT_gpencil_channel', 'DOPESHEET_MT_gpencil_frame', 'GPENCIL_OT_active_frame_delete', 'GPENCIL_OT_convert', 'GPENCIL_OT_data_add', 'GPENCIL_OT_data_unlink', 'GPENCIL_OT_draw', 'GPENCIL_OT_layer_add', 'GPencilFrame', 'GPencilFrames', 'GPencilLayer', 'GPencilStroke', 'GPencilStrokePoint', 'GPencilStrokePoints', 'GPencilStrokes', 'GreasePencil', 'GreasePencilLayers']
```

This revealed something useful: The naming scheme. Grease Pencil operators start with `GPENCIL`.

Time to [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) the Blender sources! `GPENCIL_PT_` won't match anything, this kind of abstraction isn't really used in the C code. But we know there are buttons (=operators) drawn in the panel, so we can search for them and try to locate what adds them to the layout - `GPENCIL_OT_` finds `blender\source\blender\editors\gpencil\gpencil_buttons.c` among other files.

`GPENCIL_OT_data_add` is the first match, on line 306 it reads:

```
    uiTemplateID(col, C, ctx_ptr, "grease_pencil", "GPENCIL_OT_data_add", NULL, "GPENCIL_OT_data_unlink");
```

This is part of the function `draw_gpencil_panel()`, this is defintely the right place.

UI widgets are directly added to the layout:

```
uiItemO(col, IFACE_("New Layer"), ICON_NONE, "GPENCIL_OT_layer_add");
```

This is obviously the C-equivalent of

```
col.operator("gpencil.layer_add", text="New Layer")
```

Some of the functions could probably be ported to python, but others can't. Take the 3D View layers widget for example: it draws nice little orange dots on the layers, which have at least one object on them. We couldn't do this nicely in python.